# Migrate from native to EclipseLink persistence

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, toplink

My application is using Spring 2.5, and native TopLink 10g. I want to migrate my application from native TopLink to EclipseLink.

Currently each DAO in my application `extends TopLinkDaoSupport.java` (in Spring 2.5), in order to use the `#getSession()` method for all DB operations, but the return type of the method is `oracle.toplink.sessions.Session` instead of `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions`.

Is there any solution of said problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using the JPA API? That way, you could just simply inject an `EntityManager` to you DAOs.

Comment: yes, I can. But JPA required to much changes/efforts as each DAO extensively using getTopLinkTemplate() method for reading records from DB.

Comment: You should use `JpaDaoSupport` then, though I don't know how extensive changes are needed. I would definitely would go the `EntityManager` way, especially if I would migrate to the reference implementation of JPA 2 :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend to use JPA instead of the old TopLink API.
If you really need access to Session object, you can get it from `EntityManager` too. Check `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl` in `EclipseLink` - this is a class that implements `EntityManager`. There is a `getDelegate()`  method implemented that returns this `(EntityManagerImpl)` so `((org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaEntityManager)[EntityManager].getDelegate()).getActiveSession()` gives you `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session`.

Comment: Can I use existing “toplink-mapping.xml,  and session.xml” in JPA or I have to redefine all my entities in persistence.xml,

Comment: Yes you can use the existing mapping files.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_EclipseLink_Files_for_Deployment_(ELUG)#JPA_Applications_and_Session_Metadata